# Group MySQL results using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in my database that stores data about 100 or so people. It stores when they started a job and also things like marital status & city of birth.

```
CREATE TABLE `entries` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `commencement_date` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `marital_status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `employment_status` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `entries` (`id`, `city`, `commencement_date`, `marital_status`, `employment_status`) VALUES
(1, 'Glasgow', '01/04/2017', 'Married', 'Employed'),
(2, 'Glasgow', '04/04/2017', 'Married', 'Self-Employed'),
(3, 'Edinburgh', '01/04/2017', 'Single', 'Self-Employed'),
(4, 'Glasgow', '04/04/2017', 'Single', 'Employed'),
(5, 'North London', '01/04/2017', 'Divorced', 'Unemployed'),
(6, 'Glasgow', '04/04/2017', '', 'Self-Employed');

ALTER TABLE `entries`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

I use the following PHP to grab this data from the database:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM entries WHERE city = '$city' AND (commencement_date BETWEEN '$dateStart' AND '$dateEnd')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

However, I am wondering, is it possible using PHP to total the number of Married, Single & Divorced and list these in a bullet list?

Preferably, my script should output:

```
Married: 2
Single: 2
Divorced: 1
```

I'm just wondering if there's a tidy way of doing this with PHP.

Comment: Why not use mysql query for this??

Comment: @Saty Can I use MySQL for this? Longer term, I think I'll have lots of data to display in this fashion (using the one query) e.g. employment status, city of birth...can I use a MySQL query to organise all this?

Comment: And, an completely off-topic comment on the ethics of the question: Why does an employer keep track of the marital status of the employees?

Comment: You can use mysql for this purpose. There is a function called  `COUNT`, you can pass withing the brackets e.g. another `SELECT` statement. An example for married people would be `"SELECT COUNT(SELECT * FROM entries WHERE marital_status = 'Married') FROM entries WHERE city = '$city' AND (commencement_date BETWEEN '$dateStart' AND '$dateEnd')";) FROM entries WHERE city = '$city' AND (commencement_date BETWEEN '$dateStart' AND '$dateEnd')";`

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I doubt it's about ethics. Is simply breaking the law in most countries, so one lawsuit should be sufficient to patch this.

Comment: @TobiasF Thanks for this. I'm just wondering, will this result in a lot of requests to the database for each particular scenario? I wasn't sure whether there was a better way of PHP taking all the results and then grouping them from there.

Comment: You can gather all statuses in a single request. This is basic stuff. As an aside, it's not possible to define a primary key separately from an auto_increment, so something odd there - and store dates using an appropriate data type!!

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Mysql is quite faster at grouping and counting your results than PHP, and it already delivers the data, so why not let it handle this counting as well?

Comment: @TobiasF. I like your thinking :) I think I will try with MySQL first.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware : my father's used to do that, along with number of children, so that we all had gifts on our birthday and x-mas from his company. But I agree on ethics **AND** MySQL...  @michaelmcgurk [MySQL count](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html) and [MySQL group](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) and/or even `group by`. you read it, you mix it...

Comment: To be fair, you could do this just as effectively in PHP or JavaScript. Tobias' assertions about relative performance are a little unfounded.

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for your input, Strawberry :) Would you recommend I grab all the results with MySQL and use PHP to group them into `Marital Status`, `Employment Status` etc.?

Comment: @Strawberry thats what i think how it is. If i'm wrong feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below query to get total

```
$sql = "SELECT marital_status , count(id) as total FROM entries GROUP BY marital_status";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this query. I hope it will work.

```
$sql = "SELECT marital_status, count(*)
  FROM entries
  GROUP BY marital_status";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function totalEntriesBasedOnMartialStatus($conn, $marital_status){
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) as totalEntries FROM entries WHERE marital_status=:marital_status");
    $query->execute(array(':marital_status'=>$marital_status));
    $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $row['totalEntries'];
}
```

Please try this function i hope it will work you need to pass martial status for which you want to get total.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id,
sum(case when marital_status = 'Single' then 1 else 0 end) singlesum,
sum(case when marital_status = 'Marrid' then 1 else 0 end) marridsum
from entries
order by id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL for it:

```
SELECT marital_status, count(*) FROM `entries` GROUP BY marital_status
```

Or PHP:

```
$count_married=$count_divorced=$count_single=0;
foreach($result as $next_result) {
   if($next_result['marital_status'] === 'Divorced') {
      $count_divorced++;
   }
   if($next_result['marital_status'] === 'Single') {
      $count_single++;
   }
   if($next_result['marital_status'] === 'Married') {
      $count_married++;
   }
}

echo "Married: $count_married<br />\n";
echo "Single: $count_single<br />\n";
echo "Divorced: $count_divorced<br />\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below query to fetch exact what you want:

```
SELECT CONCAT(`marital_status`,":",COUNT(`id`)) FROM entries where marital_status!='' GROUP BY `marital_status` ORDER BY COUNT(`id`) DESC
```

Hope it will help you!